# show content of JPanel in JFrame

Tags: java, swing

The problem is:
I've got trigger on right mouse button click for my jpanel.(MyJPanel). When I press it it shows popup menu with item "Preview".[image: right mouse button click on jpanel]

I want to show JFrame after I press "preview" but I don't know how to show content of jpanel   because actionlistener of preview(jmenuitem) is inside MyJpanel.

```
public MyJPanel(String s,int i){
    addMouseListener(new PopupTrigger());
    JPanel obh = new JPanel();
    number = i;
    picture = new ImageIcon(s);
    preview = new JMenuItem("Preview");
    preview.addActionListener(
            new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    JFrame f = new JFrame("Preview window");
                    f.setSize(csizeX/2,csizeY/2);

                    f.setVisible(true);
                }
            }
    );
    menu.add(preview);
}
```

How to set content of jframe f to show MyJPanel?(PopupTrigger extends MouseAdapter and it's inner class of MyJPanel)

Comment: `picture = new ImageIcon(s);`  Presumes `s` is a file path.  Is this image an embedded application resource, or is it supplied by the user?  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: I get `s` from `File f = fileChooser.getSelectedFile()` `f.getAbsolutePath`

Answer (score 1):

First you need to mark JPanel final:
`final Jpanel obh`... 
to become accesible from the inner class.
then, inside the listener

```
f.getContentPane().add(obh);
```

Comment: remember to check the javadoc api: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html

Answer (score 1):

Make obh `final` and then add it to the JFrame.

Answer (score 1):

did you try jFrame.setContentPane(newcontentPanel) ?